# Определить текст, который поместится в UIlabel

Tags: objective-c, ios

У меня есть `UILabel` и строка `NSString`. Я хочу определить текст, который полностью помещается в `UIlabel` по ширине. Пример:

```
NSString* longString=@"Большая длинная строка для определения вхождения в UIlabel";
```

Результатом должно быть "Большая длинная", т.к. перенос идет по словам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Еще актуально?
Красивого ответа не нашел. Прийдется воротить велосипеды.

```
+ (NSString *)string:(NSString *)inputString thatFitsWidth:(CGFloat)width withFont:(UIFont *)font
{
    NSArray *wordsArr = [inputString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSString *resultString = [NSString new];
    for ( NSString *word in wordsArr )
    {
        NSString *iteratorString = [resultString stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@", word];
        CGSize resultSize = [iteratorString sizeWithFont:font];
        if ( resultSize.width > width )
        {
            return resultString;
        }
        resultString = iteratorString;
    }
    return resultString;
}
```

пример:

[MyAwesomeManager string:@"Большая длинная строка для определения вхождения в UIlabel" thatFitsWidth:textLabel.bounds.size.width withFont:textLabel.font];

Answer (score 0):

```
BOOL fits = [string boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(300, 999)
                                                 options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                              attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:self.stringLabel.font}
                                                 context:nil].size.height > self.stringLabel.font.pointSize
```